# How to call OpenSSL SRP APIs from Android app?

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl, java-native-interface, single-responsibility-principle

I am trying to implement the [SRP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol) for a Server and Client app in Android. I checked that OpenSSL supports SRP protocol but how can I access OpenSSL APIs from the Android app? Is JNI the only way to access the OpenSSL C APIs? Are there any samples that I can refer how to build the OpenSSL for Android and to call the OpenSSL SRP APIs through JNI.

Comment: Did you ever get SRP working under Android using OpenSSL? I really like the cipher because of its security properties.

Comment: I am trying out the Java implementation https://code.google.com/archive/p/srpforjava/downloads since it doesn't deal with JNI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to implement the [SRP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol)

I like SRP, too. Be sure to use Thomas Wu's specification, or version 6 of the IETF's specification.

---

> OpenSSL supports SRP protocol but how can I access OpenSSL APIs from the Android app? Is JNI the only way to access the OpenSSL C APIs?

Yes.

You might also look to Bouncy Castle for a Java implementation.

---

> Are there any samples that I can refer how to build the OpenSSL for Android...

See [OpenSSL and Android](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Android carries around a copy of OpenSSL, but I'm not sure of it includes SRP.

---

> Are there any samples that I can refer ... to call the OpenSSL SRP APIs through JNI.

Not that I am aware. The closest you will find is the source code to `s_client`, options like `-srpuser <user>`, and data structures like `srp_arg_st`, and functions like `ssl_srp_verify_param_cb` and `ssl_give_srp_client_pwd_cb`.

You can find the source code for `s_client` at `<openssl src dir>/apps/s_client.c`. Line 1365 looks interesting (from 1.0.2h):

```
# ifndef OPENSSL_NO_SRP
    if (srp_arg.srplogin) {
        if (!srp_lateuser && !SSL_CTX_set_srp_username(ctx, srp_arg.srplogin)) {
            BIO_printf(bio_err, "Unable to set SRP username\n");
            goto end;
        }
        srp_arg.msg = c_msg;
        srp_arg.debug = c_debug;
        SSL_CTX_set_srp_cb_arg(ctx, &srp_arg);
        SSL_CTX_set_srp_client_pwd_callback(ctx, ssl_give_srp_client_pwd_cb);
        SSL_CTX_set_srp_strength(ctx, srp_arg.strength);
        if (c_msg || c_debug || srp_arg.amp == 0)
            SSL_CTX_set_srp_verify_param_callback(ctx,
                                                  ssl_srp_verify_param_cb);
    }
# endif
```

And the `srp_arg_st` from around line 475:

```
/* This is a context that we pass to all callbacks */
typedef struct srp_arg_st {
    char *srppassin;
    char *srplogin;
    int msg;                    /* copy from c_msg */
    int debug;                  /* copy from c_debug */
    int amp;                    /* allow more groups */
    int strength /* minimal size for N */ ;
} SRP_ARG;
```

Obviously, OpenSSL is native C and does not use JNI.

---

> How to call OpenSSL SRP APIs ...?

At the highest levels, you need to do two or three things in C. Think of them as a supplement to a the standard [TLS Client](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) from the OpenSSL wiki. (I'm side stepping Android/JNI part).

*First*, you need to set the `SSL_CTX_set_srp_*_callback`. The callbacks are how the library prompts your TLS client for information like username and password.

*Second*, you remove all non-SRP cipher suites. That means you *do not* use a cipher list like *`"HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!RC4"`*.

*Third*, you use only SRP cipher suites. I'm not sure how the cipher list would look when using `"HIGH:!aNULL:..."`. But you can hand pick the list of ciphers with:

```
$ openssl ciphers -v | grep SRP | grep -v DSS | cut -f 1 -d ' '
SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA
SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA
SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA
SRP-AES-128-CBC-SHA
SRP-RSA-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
SRP-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
```

If you go to the [`openssl ciphers` man page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ciphers.html), then you should be able to cross reference `SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA` with the name needed in the cipher list. Unfortunately, the SRP cipher suites are missing.

However, you can go to ICANN's [TLS paramter registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml) and get the names:

- SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA → TLS_SRP_SHA_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
- SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA → TLS_SRP_SHA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
- SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA → TLS_SRP_SHA_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
- SRP-AES-128-CBC-SHA → TLS_SRP_SHA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
- SRP-RSA-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA → TLS_SRP_SHA_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
- SRP-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA → TLS_SRP_SHA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

So the string you would use for `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list` or `SSL_set_cipher_list`:

```
static const char const PREFERRED_CIPHERS[] =
   "TLS_SRP_SHA_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:TLS_SRP_SHA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:
    TLS_SRP_SHA_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_SRP_SHA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:
    TLS_SRP_SHA_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:TLS_SRP_SHA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA";
```